# NSQ trendrr : Is it possible to get the queue size with client?

Tags: queue, java-7, nsq

I'm using this classes at the moment:

- com.trendrr.nsq.NSQProducer
- com.trendrr.nsq.NSQConsumer

My service needs to know how many messages are queued at the moment, because there is some "when it will be done" estimation method.

Does someone knows how to get the actual queue size? Perhaps with some other java implementations?

What I found:

- https://github.com/brainlag/JavaNSQClient (consumer has some getTotalMessages() method but it is a total processed msg counter)